# Add array into object

Tags: javascript

If I have an Object like.

```
myObj = {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30
}
```

and an array like this.

```
myObjArr = [
    { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
]
```

How can I merge my array into the object so the output is like

```
myObj = {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": [
        { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
        { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
        { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
    ]
}
```

Sorry if this is a redundant question, but for some reason I just get lost with arrays. I have tried push which did not work and cannot find any good example on how to do this.

Comment: This is very basic JS stuff, not even related to json. Ex: `myObj.cars = myObjArr`

Comment: Pls demonstrate what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the array as a value to the key "cars"

```
myObj['cars'] = myObjArr;
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that `myObj.cars` and `myObjArr` now refer to the same object; changes to one will be reflected in the other

Comment: Thanks. Very similar to how I would do it with PHP why JS confuses me is beyond me.  Appreciate the help .

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values represented by a particular key value using the `.` operator.
Hence, `myObj.cars` should be the value at position represented by the key `cars`.

So, in order to assign the array in `myObjArr` to that position in the JSON, it's just the following:

```
myObj.cars = myObjArr;
```